# How to remove gap/space between widget and layout child in Elementor?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, elementor

in Elementor, by default if we add layout inside an widget, we can see there's a gap or space between widget and layout (widget's child), as seen in below picture:

[image]

is there any way to remove it, because I still cant found it.

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming, it's related to WordPress and a site builder extension

Comment: Check with Dev. Tools which element the parent is and override its inner spacing (`padding`), or override the default outer spacing of the child (`margin`).

Comment: Would need the code of your layout (html + css) to find out, why there is a gap.

Comment: First, check Elementor itself, for that particular block. There should be an option for margin/padding. Try setting it to 0 and see if it fixes? Else, right click that particular spot , go to inspect element and Select that spot to highlight it and see where the margin/padding is coming from. Then add a css to make it 0. Works the same for WP Bakery / Visual composer / Elementor or any other page builders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default elementor adds padding for columns and margin of 20px between each widget. To change it, click on the column and change the widget gap to 0 or whatever you want, then go to the advanced tab and change the padding to 0;

You can also set the widget gap globally to what you want in the elementor settings

Comment: Props to this answer. In case it helps anyone else, you can edit a column by right click inside the gap area and choose "Edit Column".